# Android studio 2.3 won't start

Tags: android-studio-2.3

I upgraded from studio 2.2 to 2.3 yesterday and when it tried to restart it crashed.

I managed to see a setup wizard for a second but it crashes before I can click on anything.

I opened an issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=267715) and decided to install from scratch.
Studio is still crashing - I tried the cleanup described [here](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fa%2F18458893%2F2482564&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGz_U7i4NXxUnAdXewNaNramBGlVQ) and nothing helps.

I updated the JVM to the latest version and nothing changed

This is the crash info I get from the mac

```
Process:               studio [772]
Path:                  /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Identifier:            com.google.android.studio
Version:               2.3 (AI-162.3764568)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           studio [772]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-03-29 16:36:14.789 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        E4F7576D-259B-A697-034A-7B7D528789D6


Time Awake Since Boot: 430 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

- [the full crash report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1MnnD7rqBMWQ2w1RmtCQmJMTEU/view?usp=sharing)
- [this is the java error log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1MnnD7rqBMWNW04MVUxWnVaVU0/view?usp=sharing)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the mac crash - a coworker found this line
"JRSInputMethodController availableInputMethodLocales" which led to [this known issue](https://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2015/Sep/msg00006.html) of JRE crashing due to additional inputs, I removed my additional keyboard layout and the crash went away.

As stated in the issue - it is fixed in OS X 10.11 or a lower java version - I'm on OS X 10.10 so I'll upgrade to 10.11

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Download this file: http://tools.android.com/knownissues/studio and replace Studio's Contents/MacOS/studio

In Terminal run this line:
chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio

Done :)